# Can we install PGPool on Master/StandBY Postgres DB Server

Tags: postgresql-9.3, high-availability, pgpool

As per the standard practice, we install the PGPool in separate instances. This increases a separate hardware for PGPool. Although, they are in HA mode it consumes minimum 2 servers.

So instead of doing this, can we install it on Master/Standby Servers (in HA Mode) to minimize the hardware requirements and separate instances.

I found several posts that it is possible but not recommended, but if the question is for Cost and only for DEV Environment.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Mandar P.

Comment: If you use PGPool for HA then installing it on the master makes no sense. If the master goes down, then you pool stops working as well. And if this is only for DEV, then I wouldn't bother with a standby or pgPool at all.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure that PG and pgpool-II should not use the same port numbers, otherwise technically, there is no issue with installing the PostgreSQL server and pgpool-II on the same machine.

Comment: Yes, Surely will have to run it on another port otherwise we are getting the port conflict